# How to get first and last values in numpy arange?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, range, python-2.x

I have a list that created from numpy.arange, I want to create an interval which the top and bottom values is from a list that can be accessed for other list later.

Table shown:

```
|------------------------------------|
| Probability Cumulative | Interval  |
|------------------------------------|
|           3            |  0  - 2   |
|           27           |  3  - 26  |
|           60           |  27 - 59  |
|           72           |  60 - 71  |
|           88           |  72 - 87  |
|           92           |  88 - 91  |
|           100          |  92 - 99  |
|------------------------------------|
```

Here is my raw code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> prob_cumulative = [3, 27, 60, 72, 88, 92, 100]
>>> for x in prob_cumulative:
>>>    newList = np.arange(0,x)
>>>    print newList

[0 1 2]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74
 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74
 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74
 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
```

If I do this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> for x in prob_cumulative:
>>>    newList = np.arange(0,x)
>>>    top = newList[-1]
>>>    bot = newList[0]
>>>    print bot,top
0 2
0 26
0 59
0 71
0 87
0 91
0 99
```

I got the top values for each list, because np.arange(**0**,x), my bottom values got 0. How to get the bottom values which started from the last values of top + 1 like shown in the table?

EDIT:
With this:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>prob_cumulative = [3, 27, 60, 72, 88, 92, 100]
>>>bot=0
>>>for x in prob_cumulative:
>>>   newList = np.arange(bot,x)
>>>   top = newList[-1]
>>>   bot = top+1
>>>   print newList
[0 1 2]
[ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
[27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
[60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
[72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87]
[88 89 90 91]
[92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deepin@deepin-pc:~/test$ python test_list.py 
0
[0, 1, 2]
3
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
27
[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
60
[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71]
72
[72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87]
88
[88, 89, 90, 91]
92
[92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
deepin@deepin-pc:~/test$ cat test_list.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

prob_cumulative = [3, 27, 60, 72, 88, 92, 100]
lastvalue = 0
for x in prob_cumulative:
    print(lastvalue)
    newList = range(lastvalue, x)
    print(newList)
    lastvalue = x
deepin@deepin-pc:~/test$
```

Answer (score 0):

"How to get the bottom values which started from the last values of top + 1 like shown in the table?"

```
t = 0
import numpy as np
prob_cumulative = [3, 27, 60, 72, 88, 92, 100]
for x in prob_cumulative:
    newList = np.arange(t,x)
    print newList
    t = x + 1
```